# Solving Equations using intervals

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation for solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

1. $\sqrt{ 2 \cos(2x)}=1$
2. $\sin (x) \cos (x)= 1/2$

Comment: the first equation $$\sqrt{2\cos(2x)}=1$$

Comment: the second one $$\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

First one:

Squaring both sides,
$$2\cos(2x)=1$$
$$\implies\cos(2x)=1/2$$
$$\implies2x = \pi/3 \ or\ 5\pi/3 $$ 
$$So, x = \pi/6 \ or\ 5\pi/6$$

The second one :
$\sin(x)\cos(x)={1}/{2}$
$$\implies 2\sin(x)cos(x)=1$$
$$\implies\sin(2x)=1 
$$$$\implies2x=\pi/2$$
$$\implies x = \pi/4$$

These values are in the given interval.

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation, if you square both sides, you get $2\cos(2x)=1$. How is this different? Since the original equation was under a radical, it must be positive. So we don't want values of $x$ where cosine is negative. (What quadrants are those?)

So:
$2\cos(2x)=1$
$\cos(2x)=\frac{1}{2}$

What values on the unit circle have a cosine value of $\frac{1}{2}$? That's right, $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$. So $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ or $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$.